# Always using remote repository in egit

Tags: java, eclipse, github, egit

I have gone thru the egit tutorial doc here http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide.

I now have a git repository with an eclipse project on my laptop and can push this to a remote git repository on git hub. However, this means I have two git repositories  - one local and one remote.  I'm thinking I'd prefer to just use the remote one only. This would mean any time I commit, it commits to the remote and there is no local repository.

Is it possible to this egit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

git is a [distributed version control system](http://betterexplained.com/articles/intro-to-distributed-version-control-illustrated/). By definition this means that each developer has its own repository.

I have not experience with egit but you can [configure a hook to automatically make a push after a commit](http://snipplr.com/view/7165/).

Also, in a git *cli* you could set [an alias](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases) to make the commit and push process in only one step, but anyway, the local repository will be need.

Comment: So every developer *has* to have its own repository?   Interesting idea on alias

Comment: I edit my post to give another option, and set a link to an explanation of the alias

Answer (score 0):

You should always have a local repository to work with. First pull the repository to local repository, perform changes and push back to the remote repository.